# How visualize ViewBag in a OnFailure function?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

I used an Ajax.BeginForm with OnFailure function. But I can't visualize the text with the error I set inside before in the controller.

Controller

```
if(error==3) {
 ViewBag.Errore="You have to ...";
 throw new Exception("You have to ...";
}
```

View

```
<div id="error"></div>
     @using (Ajax.BeginForm...., new AjaxOptions() {
    ....
    ....
    OnFailure="OnFailure"
    }
....
<script type="text/javascript"> 

function Onfailure() {
$("#error").text('@ViewBag.Errore');
}
</script>
```

If I use $("#error").text("error"); it works properly.

What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

This code only runs *once* in that scenario:

```
@ViewBag.Errore
```

It's interpreted when the page is loaded, then never again (until the page is loaded again, basically).  So any AJAX interactions aren't going to update that server-side value to re-interpret it for client-side output.  AJAX is run asynchronously via JavaScript, so you're going to have to get the error with JavaScript code instead of Razor code.

If I remember correctly, `OnFailure` passes an argument to the JavaScript function it calls.  So you can get information from that argument.  Something like this:

```
function Onfailure(errorContext) {
    $("#error").text('The request failed with status code: ' + errorContext.get_statusCode());
}
```

There's probably a lot of useful data about the request/response in that `errorContext`, and I don't have a reference for it handy.  But it's worth putting a breakpoint there in your JavaScript debugger and seeing what else it contains.  For example, if the AJAX response body contains the error message, you might do something like this:

```
function Onfailure(errorContext) {
    $("#error").text(errorContext.get_response());
}
```

Also of note, I think case-sensitivity matters here.  So you probably want to either rename the function to `OnFailure` or change the `BeginForm` property you're setting to `OnFailure="Onfailure"`.

Comment: Hi, I understood but that code doesn't work once ... why? get_response doesn't exist!

Comment: @SanginetoS.: What isn't working in this code?  Is `errorContext` not being supplied when the function is called?  Have you fixed the case-sensitivity issue?  Is there an error on the JavaScript console in the browser?

Comment: In my console there is only the erro for my exception I can't see anything else.

Comment: @SanginetoS.: Can you place a breakpoint inside the `OnFailure` function in your browser's JavaScript debugger to see if it's ever called at all?  Maybe update your question with a screenshot of what you *are* seeing?

Comment: Sorry, I never used the console with debugger until now. I'm trying but I don't see that code in my page (script section), maybe because I have 3 partial pages different? I'm sure that the function is called because if I print the text It works properly.

Comment: @SanginetoS.: If the code is being called then it has to be in the page somewhere.  "Partial" pages/views are a server-side concept, on the client it renders as a single DOM.  For debugging JavaScript you're definitely going to want to familiarize yourself with the browser's debugging tools.

Comment: I have a main page called Man_port and three partial view inside. When i load the sources tab in the debbugging tool I see only some rows about it. Why?

Comment: @SanginetoS.: Is "sources" the different requests to the server?  There would only be one request for a page.  As I said, "partial view" is a server-side concept.  From the browser's perspective, there's only one page.

Comment: I understood but I'm trying to explain you the following situation: I have a main page called man_port, in this page I have 3 portions (partial view) with three div differents. The first div is loaded at the start of the main page, I can see inside this div all the javascript sections. For the other 2 div that are loaded after the click on the first form (first div) I don't find the javascript in the tab sources when i use the debugging tool!